# What are the longest English vowel phonemes?

Tags: pronunciation

What are the [longest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length) vowel phonemes in English using IPA notation?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question makes any sense. Because length isn't phonemic, it can vary from one utterance to the next. Even though you would likely find the vowel of *beat* to be longer than that of *bit*, it’s unclear how that stacks up to *beatitude*’s.

Comment: @tchrist It's good that we have your comment here. The question asks about phonemes (vowels only) regardless of the words they are used in.

Comment: I'm still confused by the question. The linked Wikipedia article says "Many languages do not distinguish vowel length phonemically. Those that do usually distinguish between short vowels and long vowels. A very few languages distinguish three phonemic vowel lengths, such as Luiseño and Mixe." This implies that the "longest" vowel phonemes in English will constitute one set out of at most two or three sets of vowel phonemes.

Comment: This seems like an odd way to phrase the question if that's what you're asking about, though, and you can find out which vowel phonemes are considered long and which ones are considered short just by reading some description of the phonology of English vowels like the following blog post by Geoff Lindsey: http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/british-vowels/ (Of course, different accents have different phonemic inventories of vowels.)

Comment: Oh, based on your [ELL version of this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158895/what-are-the-longest-vowels-in-english), it seems you are interested in phonetic length. In that case, it's actually important to consider not only the identity of the vowel phoneme, but the identity of the following consonant phoneme (if there is any). One of the basic principles of phonetic vowel length in English is that a vowel phoneme before a voiceless consonant, or just in a syllable that ends in a voiceless consonant, is phonetically shorter than the same vowel phoneme in other contexts.

Comment: So for example, the word "bead" has a phonetically longer vowel than the word "beat", and the word "lab" has a phonetically longer vowel than than the word "lap".

Comment: Are you talking about American English or British English? They're different.

Comment: @PeterShor  Thanks for your commit. If different mentioning both would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure what IPA has to do with it, but the longest vowel sound is probably "Aaah!" or  the "o" in "No!", shouted by a movie villain when [being dispatched](http://junkee.com/this-supercut-of-disney-villains-falling-to-their-deaths-is-immensely-satisfying/55330).

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checked_and_free_vowels, where the checked/lax ones are “short” and the free/tense ones are “long”.

Comment: @Lawrence Those two could perhaps be narrowly transcribed phonetically as [ɑːːə̯] for *“Aaah!”* and [noːːʊ̯] for *“No!”*, but that just tells you how they sound — it is not phonemic, which would still be simply /ɑ/ and /no/ without a bunch of funny little marks.  

Comment: @tchrist I understand that my comment doesn't properly answer the question ... which is why I left it as a comment. I don't see the connection between phonemes and duration. There are vowel sounds *labelled* 'short' or 'long', but how long one holds a vowel sound doesn't depend entirely on that label. For example, "bit" has a 'short' vowel sound, but the phrase "a bit of a stretch" can be spoken with the 'i' stretched over a few seconds. Likewise with the 'e' in *stretch*. On the other hand, the 'ee' in *street* can be spoken quite quickly even though that's a 'long' vowel sound.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking about diphthongs and triphthongs? Are you asking about short vs long vowels? Are you asking about standard or American or British or about any dialect of English? Can you give examples of things you're considering?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the Guinness Book of Records.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/408728), that did experiments in the 1930s in the U.S., /ɪ/, /ʊ/, /ɛ/, and /ʌ/ are all fairly short, whereas the rest of the vowels and diphthongs are fairly long.

There are variations among the long and among the short vowels, but I can't tell whether these are these are statistically significant — they're relatively small and in some cases they depended on the speaker. The variations caused by the consonant following the vowel are much larger—the vowel in *bay* was nearly twice as long as the vowel in *bake*.

In British English, the vowel /ɒ/ is also short. Traditionally, the vowel /a/ was short, but it's not clear whether this is still the case. Finally, in British English, vowel length is considerably more important in terms of distinguishing vowels than in American English—it's evolving so that the pairs *beard*, *bid* and *bared, bed* are distinguished primarily by vowel length, and vowel length is an important element in distinguishing the pair *port, pot*, and possibly in distinguishing *cart* and *cut*.

Comment: I would think that the vowel in *pot* would be short for most Americans, too, whether they say that one as a flat /pɑt/ or somewhat rounded as /pɒt/. Even diphthongs are subject to some shortening before an unvoiced consonant, as in short *tight* /taɪt/, [tʰʌɪ̯t̚] versus longer *died* /daɪd/, [dɐˑɪ̯d]; or short *writer* /ˈraɪtɚ/,  [ˈɹʌɪ̯ɾɚ] versus longer *rider* /ˈraɪdɚ/, [ˈɹɐˑɪ̯ɾɚ], under the phenomenon commonly known as Canadian raising but common to all English-speaking North America. (In the narrow transcriptions I’ve used the “half-long” mark `ˑ` after the longer diphthongs’ main vowels.)

Comment: @tchrist: all vowels are shortened before unvoiced consonants, but according to the paper, *pot* is considerably longer than *pit* and *put*, and around the same length as *boat* and *date*, as well as *bud* and *bed*.